# Android Loading Image from URL in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview

I am Reading imageURL's From Rss Xml file and displaying in List View,I'm able to display the images ,but getting Exception For Some Image URL's

**java.io.FileNotFoundException**

Here My Code:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 
    String type;
    public ImageLoader(Context context,String type){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        this.type=type;
    } 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }    
    final int stub_id = R.drawable.toriimg;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //Log.d("ImageLoader","Iam in DisplayImage");
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);           
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
           int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            if(this.type=="SongPlayActivity")
            {

                scale=1;

            }
            else if(this.type=="AlbumPlayListActivity")
            {


                scale=1;
            }
            else
            {

            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }
            }
            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.toucheradio.com/hostphotos/kiran Abbaraju.jpg
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at com.teluguone.torilt.model.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:89)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at com.teluguone.torilt.model.ImageLoader.access$0(ImageLoader.java:72)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at com.teluguone.torilt.model.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:163)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-14 13:00:09.640: W/System.err(11295):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Could any one Suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I say in one of my comments, if you encode "http://" you will get "http%3A%2F%2F". The URLEncoder.encode method is for encoding query string values rather than whole URLs.

So, one solution can be:

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("kiran Abbaraju.jpg", "utf-8");
String url = "http://www.toucheradio.com/hostphotos/" + query;
```

But a cleaner solution is:

```
String wrongUrl = "http://www.toucheradio.com/hostphotos/kiran Abbaraju.jpg";
URL url = new URL(wrongUrl);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

UPDATE:

In your getBitmap(String url) try:

```
...
//from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        URI uri = new URI(imageUrl.getProtocol(), imageUrl.getUserInfo(), imageUrl.getHost(), imageUrl.getPort(), imageUrl.getPath(), imageUrl.getQuery(), imageUrl.getRef());
        imageUrl = uri.toURL();
...
```

Comment: Could you tell me where Should i pass url reference ?this line url = uri.toURL();

Answer (score 3):

as in log:

> FileNotFoundException: http://www.toucheradio.com/hostphotos/kiran
>   Abbaraju.jpg

you are passing space in url with image name`(kiran Abbaraju.jpg)` so use `URLEncoder.encode` for ecoding it before requesting image from url  as:

```
String img_url="http://www.toucheradio.com/hostphotos/kiran Abbaraju.jpg";
String finalimageurl = URLEncoder.encode(your_img_url,"UTF-8");
```

Comment: I removed the white spaces from Image Url,but again getting with the Same Exception,Could you Suggest

Comment: If you encode "http://" you will get "http%3A%2F%2F". The URLEncoder.encode method is for encoding query string values rather than whole URLs.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getBitmap`, you need to encode the url first using `URLEncoder` before trying to open it using `getFile`

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do someting like this :

```
  private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
            {
                url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
               .....YOUR CODE
```

Comment: This way, you are only fixing the spaces problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please use universal image Loader , it is better method to load image from url it will handle all exceptions and issues,

For this first read image Link from xml, and then within adapter use universal image Loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16557816/1911784

Answer (score 1):

In Adapter of your project...use this code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            holder.tv_ResName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvResName);
            holder.imgLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgID);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_ResName.setText(ParseRestaurant.resStorage.get(position).getResName());
        String url_val=ParseRestaurant.resStorage.get(position).getResLogo();//This is the Url you are getting from JSON parsing
        URL url;
          Bitmap  bmImg;
        try {
            url = new URL(url_val);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
             bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
             holder.imgLogo.setImageBitmap(bmImg); //Here u will set image in imageview
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```