# Download image from a url and show in a listview

Tags: android

I am fetching title, date and image from an online xml file and storing it in a arraylist. I have taken 3 different arraylists for storing title , date and image.

I am successful in getting image urls , my problem is how to download image from the url and show it in a imageview. The code for fetching the url is below.

```
  if((xpp_name.equals("content")))
  {                                                 
xpp.next(); 
    strvalue=xpp.getText();
    if(strvalue!=null){  
        String url = strvalue.substring(
                     strvalue.indexOf("src")+5,, strvalue.indexOf("jpg")+3);
     arrayList_for_images.add(url);
    }  
    xpp.next();     
    xpp.next();}
```

Comment: Check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161137/android-download-image-from-url-and-show-in-imageview)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16560535/1911784

Comment: For listview use Lazy Loading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: Thank you Srikanth , OMAK and Naveen

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) you can find a lazy loading library to download images from a URL and show them in a `ListView`. Also i suggest you to avoid using 3 different `Arraylists` and use only one `ArrayList`, instead, with a custom class that is used to store the information of an image(title, date and image url).

**EDIT:** Here is an example class that holds the information needed for the image:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ImageObject {

    private String image_name;
    private String image_url;
    private Date image_date;

public ImageObject() {
}

public ImageObject(String image_name, String image_url, Date image_date) {

    this.image_name = image_name;
    this.image_url = image_url;
    this.image_date = image_date;
}

public void setImageName(String image_name) {

    this.image_name = image_name;
}

public void setImageURL(String image_url) {

    this.image_url = image_url;
}

public void setImageDate(Date image_date) {

    this.image_date = image_date;
}


public String getImageName() {

    return this.image_name;
}

public String getImageURL() {

    return this.image_url;
}

public Date getImageDate() {

    return this.image_date;
}
}
```

Here is an example usage in witch i initiate a `ArrayList` with one `ImageObject`:

```
ArrayList<ImageObject> data = new ArrayList<ImageObject>();
ImageObject obj = new ImageObject("test.jpg", "www.imageurl.com", new Date());
data.add(obj);
```

And this is how you retrieve a value from a certain `ImageObject` object from the `ArrayList`:

```
data.get(0).getImageName();
```

Comment: @ Angelo Thank you for replying, could you pls explain how to do the above using only one arraylist?

Comment: @user1740281 I have updated the answer with an example class. Hope that helps:)

Comment: @ Angelo : Thank you so much , I will definitely going to implement lazyload and ImageObject class in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new thread for downloading image from Url and set image in imageview in handler.

```
  private Bitmap pop_up_image_bitmap ;
  private  Handler handler ;
  private Runnable r;
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            URL newurl;
            try {
                newurl = new URL(<Url>);
                pop_up_image_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
                handler.post(r);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


        }
    }).start();
```

Put handler :

```
    handler = new Handler();
     r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if(pop_up_image_bitmap!=null){
            imageview.setImageBitmap(pop_up_image_bitmap);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            popUpImageProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: as said by @Angelo you can also use lazy loader . which is a good idea to load more images.

Comment: @ Akhilesh : Thank you for replying , I am trying to implement this also .

Answer (score 0):

try out this best  image loading library ever.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader